# Why do I get a jQuery error when using html5shiv?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, html5shiv

The following code generates a jQuery error:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>jquery-test.html</title>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<header>
    <hr>
</header>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

> Unknown runtime error jquery-1.10.2.js, line 3489 character 3
>
> line 3489: `div.innerHTML = "<table><tr><td></td><td>t</td></tr></table>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html5shiv requires an explicit `<body>` tag ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/issues/100)). The following works correctly:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>jquery-test.html</title>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<body>
    <header>
        <hr>
    </header>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</body>
```

In the simplest case you'll just get a blank screen without errors. When adding additional content like HTML or scripts, you may get obscure errors.

Comment: It's a good habit to always have explicit `html`, `head` and `body`.

Comment: @Pavlo This is the first time I run into an issue with omitting the tags (it is valid HTML after all), but perhaps it's better to be safe than sorry indeed :)